# Layout para impressão diretamente no site

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer a impressão de uma página que criei.
Quando faço a visualização para impressão o leiaute fica como a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando vou fazer a impressão está saindo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código abaixo mostra como foi montado o leiaute da página:

```
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">

       <div class="container">

           <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top:20px">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="https://www.myweg.net/irj/portal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span> </span>Portal WEG</a></li>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li style="padding-right:15px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:  #777"></span></li>
                            <li style="padding-right:15px"><span id="UserName" style="color:  #777"></span>
                            </li> </ul>

                    </ol>               
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <span id="pageTitle" class="navbar-brand" style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-bottom:0px">Registro de Autorização de Pagamento</span></div>                
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                                                            
                            <li><a href="http://www.weg.net"><img src="../SiteAssets/Imagens/weg.png" width="60px" alt="" /></a>
                            </li>               
                        </ul>                                       
                </div>
           </nav> 


        <div class="panel-group">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMainPanel">
                    <h4 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">Autorização de Pagamento</h4>
                </div>

                    <div id="collapseMainPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

                        <div class="panel-body" id="Panel1">

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Debitar a:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpDebitar" />
                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Local:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpLocal" />
                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Conta Contábil:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpContaContabil" />
                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Centro de Custo:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpCentroCusto" />
                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Modalidade de Pagamento:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpModPag" />
                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Valor:</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ImpValor"/>
                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Por Extenso:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpExtenso"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Banco:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpBanco"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Agência:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpAgencia"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Conta Corrente:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpCC"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">A Firma:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpFirma"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Cidade:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpCidade"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Estado:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpEstado"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">CPF/CNPJ:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpCPFCNPJ"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Em Data:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpData"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">                               
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Relativo a:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control" id="ImpRelativo"/>

                                </div>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <span class="text-info">Solicitante:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control-static" id="ImpSolicitante">Teste</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="text-info">Local e Data:</span>
                                    <span class="form-control-static" id="ImpLocalData">Teste2</span>
                             </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div>
                                    <span class="text-info">___________________________________________</span>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <span class="form-control-static" id="ImpLocalData">Seção Tesouraia</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div>
                                    <span class="text-info">___________________________________________</span>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <span class="form-control-static" id="ImpLocalData">Assinatura</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>





                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Sem o código, de nada adianta

Comment: Precisa do CSS também se possível. Mas provavelmente vc terá que fazer um tratamento com @print para adaptar o seu CSS para impressão. Outra coisa. Normalmente as cores e imagens usadas no Background não são reconhecidas pela impressora. Vc vai ter que usar alguma técnica para tratar isso e não ficar tudo branco

Comment: na verdade não tratei nada no CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando Bootstrap e no seu formulário você está dividindo os campos em várias colunas, mas ao dividir as colunas você está usando a classe:

```
col-sm-x
```

A classe `col-sm` vai fazer seu layout ser dividido em dispositivos com tela maior que 768 pixels. Para você forçar que o layout se mantenha o mesmo independente do tamanho da tela você pode usar

```
col-xs-x
```

Para entender melhor o sistema de grids do Bootstrap você pode acessar [esse link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)